# Proper folder permissions for passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, capistrano, passenger

I have a Rails 3 app I am running on an ubuntu 12 machine.  If I set the folder permissions for the app to be owned by the www-data user, the application comes up fine in my browser, however I can't deploy new builds to that folder using another "deployer" user I created (I get a permission denied error).  Is there a way to allow this "deployer" user to be able to deploy new code to that folder yet still have www-data read it?  I use the "deployer" user for my capistrano script.

Comment: I should add I tried setting the folder to be owned by "deployer" but then the app does not come up properly in a browser.  Also tried modifying the PassengerDefaultUser but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - why not create a group called web (or something similar) and add both "deployer" user and www-data to the group. Assign the group to be the group for the application folder.

`chgrp web folder -R`

I usually make the folder owned by the capistrano deployment user.

Comment: +1 this makes perfect sense yet perhaps I'm not doing something wrong I did `sudo groupadd web` - 
`usermod -a -G web deployer` - 
`usermod -a -G web www-data` -
`chown -R deployer my_app` - 
`chgrp web my_app -R` yet get a permission denied error in my browser